# Excel formula is not updating when SOAP UI writes the data

Tags: excel, groovy, soapui

When I run my SOAP UI project, it works fine and it updates the result i.e pass or fail in the specific column however whatever formula I have written which will take input from pass / fail result is not getting updated.

Can you please let me know any reason?

I am using SOAP UI 5.4

The code is given below

```js
import jxl.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import static org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle.*;
import static org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFormulaEvaluator;
import groovy.json.*;
import groovy.utils.*;
 
  def soapTestCase = context.testCase
  def requestPropertyVariable = soapTestCase.getTestStepByName("requestProperty")
  def globalProperties = com.eviware.soapui.model.propertyexpansion.PropertyExpansionUtils.globalProperties
  def responseText = context.expand('${responseText}')

  def inputFilePath = globalProperties.getPropertyValue("inputFilePath")
  def testDataID = globalProperties.getPropertyValue("testDataID")
  def testCaseID = globalProperties.getPropertyValue("testCaseID")
  
  int outputRowCount = Integer.parseInt((requestPropertyVariable.getPropertyValue("outputRowCount")))
  def responseStatus = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName(testCaseID).getTestRequest().response.responseHeaders.find{ it.key == "#status#" }?.value.getAt(0)  
  int k = Integer.parseInt((requestPropertyVariable.getPropertyValue("outIteration")))
  FileInputStream xlwb = new FileInputStream(new File(inputFilePath)); 
        
  def inptDataWb = new HSSFWorkbook(xlwb);
  def inputxlsh = inptDataWb.getSheetAt(2);
  def outputxlsh = inptDataWb.getSheetAt(3);
  
  String otestDataID = outputxlsh.getRow(k+1).getCell(0);
  String eleName = outputxlsh.getRow(k+1).getCell(1);
  DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
  String expectedResult = formatter.formatCellValue(outputxlsh.getRow(k+1).getCell(2));
  String mulEleFLg = outputxlsh.getRow(k+1).getCell(4);
   
//Validate results

  if (responseStatus == "HTTP/1.1 200 OK") {
  log.info "Response status code check pass"  
    def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
    def responseHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(testRunner.testCase.testSteps[testCaseID].testRequest.response.getContentAsXml())
    def tagElement = responseHolder.getNodeValue(eleName) as String  //tagElement is a value of a tag


     if(mulEleFLg=="Y"){
      responseResultArray = tagElement
      multiElementValidation(expectedResult, responseResultArray, inptDataWb, outputxlsh, inputFilePath, k)
     }else{
      if(expectedResult==tagElement.toString().replaceAll('\\[','').replaceAll('\\]','').trim()){
        FileOutputStream xlOwb = new FileOutputStream(new File(inputFilePath));
        wrtResult = outputxlsh.getRow(k+1).getCell(3);
        wrtResult.setCellValue("P");
        wrtResult = outputxlsh.getRow(k+1).getCell(5);
        wrtResult.setCellValue("");
        inptDataWb.write(xlOwb);
        xlOwb.close();
      }else{
       FileOutputStream xlOwb = new FileOutputStream(new File(inputFilePath));
       wrtResult = outputxlsh.getRow(k+1).getCell(3);
        wrtResult.setCellValue("F");
        wrtResult = outputxlsh.getRow(k+1).getCell(5);
        wrtResult.setCellValue("Expected Result is " + expectedResult + " but actual result is " + tagElement.toString().replaceAll('\\[','').replaceAll('\\]',''));
        log.info "Expected Result is " + expectedResult + " but actual result is " + tagElement.toString().replaceAll('\\[','').replaceAll('\\]','')
        inptDataWb.write(xlOwb);
        xlOwb.close();
       }
      }

  FormulaEvaluator evaluator = inptDataWb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
  for (Sheet sheet : inptDataWb) {
      for (Row r : sheet) {
          for (Cell c : r) {
              if (c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) {
                  evaluator.evaluateAll();
                  inptDataWb.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
                  log.info "Refreshed"
               }
           }
       }
  }
  }

def multiElementValidation(expectedResult, responseResultArray, inptDataWb, outputxlsh, inputFilePath, k){

 int resResArrCnt = responseResultArray.size()
 FileOutputStream xlOwb = new FileOutputStream(new File(inputFilePath));
 boolean match = false;
 if(resResArrCnt==1){
  for (item in responseResultArray)
  { 
   for (itemOfItem in item){
    log.info itemOfItem
    if(expectedResult==itemOfItem.toString().replaceAll('\\[','').replaceAll('\\]','').trim()){
     wrtResult = outputxlsh.getRow(k+1).getCell(3);
     wrtResult.setCellValue("P");
     wrtResult = outputxlsh.getRow(k+1).getCell(5);
     wrtResult.setCellValue("");
     inptDataWb.write(xlOwb);
     match = true;
     break;
    }
   }  
  }
 }else{
  for (item in responseResultArray)
  { 
   if(expectedResult==item.toString().replaceAll('\\[','').replaceAll('\\]','').trim()){
    wrtResult = outputxlsh.getRow(k+1).getCell(3);
    wrtResult.setCellValue("P");
    wrtResult = outputxlsh.getRow(k+1).getCell(5);
    wrtResult.setCellValue("");
    inptDataWb.write(xlOwb);
    match = true;
    break;
   } 
  } 
 }

 if(!match){
   wrtResult = outputxlsh.getRow(k+1).getCell(3);
   wrtResult.setCellValue("F");
   wrtResult = outputxlsh.getRow(k+1).getCell(5);
   wrtResult.setCellValue("Expected Result is " + expectedResult + " but not exist in the array");
   log.info "Expected Result is " + expectedResult + " but not exist in the array"
   inptDataWb.write(xlOwb);
 } 
 xlOwb.close()

}

def evaluateWorkbook(){
 def inputFilePath = globalProperties.getPropertyValue("inputFilePath")
 FileInputStream xlwb = new FileInputStream(new File(inputFilePath));      
 def inptDataWb = new HSSFWorkbook(xlwb);
 FormulaEvaluator evaluator = inptDataWb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
 for (Sheet sheet : inptDataWb) {
     for (Row r : sheet) {
         for (Cell c : r) {
             if (c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) {
                 evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(c);
                 log.info "Refreshed the cell"
              }
          }
      }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I have handle it in excel macro vba under openworkbook. So the workbook formula get updated when the user opens the workbook